# I need to know which user reacted to a message in discord with python to then mention him in a message sent to a channel

Tags: python, discord.py

The baseline is, I am writing a bot to open a help ticket in my server, there's a channel which has a message and a reaction, if you click that message's reaction, a message gets sent to the staff's channel to inform them that someone needs help, I want the bot to mention the user in the message, but I don't know how to get the user's name here's the code

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# Dictionary

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '.')

# Command line bot status #

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready')

# Ticket Opening #

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(reaction):
    message_id = 'message with reaction'
    if reaction.message_id == message_id:
        if reaction.emoji.name == ('️'):
            channel = client.get_channel('staff channel id')
            await channel.send('Someone Needs Help! @here')

client.run('my token')

# member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id , guild.members) # ```
````

Answer (score 0):

change the `

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(reaction):
```

to

```
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
```

You can you the user after

Comment: Thank you very much, but now it doesn't show me any errors but nothing works, it doesn't even send the message